# Add Bulk Notes to Contacts

Tags: contacts, extension

I have about 200 contacts that I need to add a bulk note to. I can add bulk activities using CiviRules, but I can't find a way to add a bulk note.

Does anyone have any ideas or know of an extension that would do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a profile with a note field, Update multiple contacts from Actions in search results and then copying the note to each contact with the little copy button beside the Note heading (this is assuming you're trying to add the same note to each contact).

Answer (score 0):

Contact import can do this. You just need to first export a list of their contact ids, then add a column with your note.

On the import screen choose Update for duplicates (the rule is irrelevant - can leave blank). On the mapping screen choose ContactID and Note.